# Convert a Dataframe to Dictonary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I have a `.csv` file with demand values ​​written like this below, which I need to transform into a dictionary to use in a mathematical optimizer

The dataframe values ​​look like this:

```
mesoregion service value 
0 Metropolitana_SP_ BAU 10000 
1 Metropolitana_SP_ VIP / Retention 3000 
2 Guarulhos BAU 5000 
3 Guarulhos VIP / Retention 1000
```

Whch i could convert to a dictionary using this command:

```py
demand = demand.set_index (['mesoregion', 'service']). T.to_dict ('list')
```

It looks like this:

```
{('Metropolitana_de_SP', 'BAU'): [10000], ('Metropolitana_de_SP', 'VIP / Retencao'): [3000], ('Guarulhos', 'BAU'): [5000], ('Guarulhos', 'VIP / Retention'): [1000]}
```

However, I need it to look like this (not as a list, but as a value for that tuple):

```
{('Metropolitana_de_SP', 'BAU'): 10000, ('Metropolitana_de_SP', 'VIP / Retencao'): 3000, ('Guarulhos', 'BAU'): 5000, ('Guarulhos', 'VIP / Retencao') : 1000}
```

Does anyone know how to help?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would be my solution:

```
# create example dataframe    
demand = pd.DataFrame([["Metropolitana_de_SP", "BAU", 10000],
                       ["Metropolitana_de_SP", "VIP / Retencao", 3000]], columns=["mesoregion", "service", "num"])
```

**Then:** Transform pandas columns into a list and save to a new column. After this, transform the list to a tuple object.

```
demand["values_as_list"] = demand[["mesoregion", "service"]].values.tolist()
demand["values_as_tuple"] = demand["values_as_list"].apply(lambda x: tuple(x))
```

Finally create the dict:

```
demand_dict = demand.set_index(['num'])["values_as_tuple"].to_dict()
print(demand_dict)
# {10000: ('Metropolitana_de_SP', 'BAU'), 3000: ('Metropolitana_de_SP', 'VIP / Retencao')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much MarkusOdenthal, you're a pro. It worked.

I just changed this:
demand_dict = demand.set_index(['num'])["values_as_tuple"].to_dict()

to this:
demand_dict = demand.set_index(["values_as_tuple"])['num'].to_dict()

To get what I wanted.

## {('Metropolitana_de_SP', 'BAU'): 10000, ('Metropolitana_de_SP', 'VIP/Retencao'): 3000, ('Guarulhos', 'BAU'): 5000, ('Guarulhos', 'VIP/Retencao'): 1000}